# How to encode curly brace in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

How can I encode curly brace `{` in tinymce?

I want  to automatically tinymce convert it to `&#123;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no configuration option in TinyMCE to do this for you.  There is a configuration option to tell TinyMCE to encode certain entities:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#entities

...but ***this only affects unicode characters above 126.***

If you need to do this your best bet would be to process this character on the server as the content is posted.